# (De-)Activating list of checkboxes using seperate box

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, multi-select

I would like to create a series of Checkboxes that can be (de-)activated at the same time using another Checkbox. When I activate the 'Select All'-Checkbox, all the Boxes are checked. However, If I deselect the 'Select All'-Box, all the Boxes stay selected.

Can someone please check what's wrong here?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#Client").multiSelect({ oneOrMoreSelected: '*' });
)};
</script>
```

HTML / PHP:

```
<div class="float-left gutter-right" style="margin-top:15px">
    <span class="label">Select Clinet</span>
    <select id="Client" name="Client[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <?php
            foreach ($this->Clients as $Client) {
                echo "<option value='".$Client->Guid."'>"
                    . $Client->FirstName . " " 
                    . $Client->LastName."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip: If you say *red leather yellow leather* 5 times it will improve your ability to read this question.

Comment: @kiran Marty was being facetious.

Comment: The issue you're having also seems to exist in the plugin demo... http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/

Comment: Hi Littm..if u see the demo..same problem i am getting here..if i click select all check box remaining check boxes are checked but if i unchecked  still checked..can u please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to replace `attr('checked')` with `is(':checked')` in `jquery.multiSelect.js`

This solution seemed to work for some people.